# How to send a PHP *variable* back to jQuery without echoing?

Tags: php, jquery, variables

I am using the ajax() function to send a string to a PHP file.

In case of a success, the PHP file echoes "the validation of the string was successful". But I would also like to send the actual string back to jQuery and put it in a div.

How can send back that string, without having to echo it along with the confirmation message?

Or should I put both messages into a string, send it to jQuery and have jQuery split that string?
What's the best way?

Comment: You can use [`json_encode($response)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), where `$response = array('success or failure', $your_string);`. Or something to that effect. The advantage of doing that is that it will escape things for you and it will generate an object JS can use without further parsing.

Comment: The comment above is a good way to do it, but I'm intrigued: do you want to send back the same string you passed to PHP? If that's the case, you don't have to. You already have the string in jQuery, just use it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your responses. I want to sanitize the string server-side because I want to append the user's input into my HTML page. Regards

Comment: @alexx0186 If you want to sanitize it, it can be done using JS as well. It would also have the benefit of not using your bandwidth or your users' bandwidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting what others have said into code, you might set up your PHP script to return a JSON-encoded object like so:

```
$result = array(
  'message' => 'the validation of the string was successful',
  'original' => 'string sent by client'
);

echo json_encode($result);
```

On the client side, you can then access each piece from your callback function like so:

```
function (result) { 
  alert(result.message);
  // do something with result.original
}
```

Comment: Hi rjz, thanks for your response. Actually I want to send the escaped version of the original string. But I'd like to know how you handle that array in JS? Just the usual `$result[0]`? Thanks a lot

Comment: Oh ok, you just answered my question! So $result[0] would work? EDIT: nevermind, I'll use your way. Thanks!

Comment: Hi rjz, I get "undefined" when I `alert(result.message)`. I did it within the "success" callback function of `ajax()`. Would that cause a problem? Thanks a lot

Comment: Hard to tell for sure, but you might try calling `console.log(result)` to make sure that you're getting the `result` you expect from the server.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your message. The problem was that I had to add "dataType: 'json'" to make it work. Regards

Answer (score 0):

I would return JSON with the string and the validation message.